# How to load JSON using ObjectMapper to map to a specific class structure?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Can I use Jackson ObjectMapper to load data from a JSON file directly into my own data structure?  I'm trying to load a map of objects from a JSON file, but not sure how to do it.

For example, given:

```
public class View{
    public String name;
    public String title;
    public String link;
}
```

I would like to create/load a map of Views in a JSON file.  So if my JSON is:

```
 {
    "login" : {
      "name" : "login",
      "title" : "Login Page",
      "link" : "login.jsp"
    },
    "logout" : {
      "name" : "logout",
      "title" : "Logout Page",
      "link" : "logout.jsp"
    }
 }
```

I would like to be able to load everything into a Map.

I've tried the following without success.  It just loads everything into a map of maps:

```
Map<String, View> views;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
views = mapper.readValue( viewFile.getInputStream(), Map.class );
```

I presume my error is telling the mapper to read it as a Map.class, but not sure how to specific it otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
Map<String, View> views = mapper.readValue( viewFile.getInputStream(), new TypeReference<Map<String, View>>() {});
```

Essentially by using a anonymous intance of `TypeReference` as a parameter, the generic type(`View`) is not erased and will be used by Jackson to cleanly generate `Map<String, View>`as response.

Comment: Perfect.  Just what I was having trouble finding.  Works great. Thanks!

Comment: And for sake of completeness, if you need to dynamically construct structure types (like, you are passed `Class<?>` of values of a `Map`), you can use `TypeFactory` to programmatically construct `JavaType` instance (`ObjectMapper.getTypeFactory()`).

Answer (score 0):

Define your class like

```
public class View{
  public View() {
  }

  public Info getLogin() {
    return login;
  }

  public void setLogin(Info login) {
    this.login = login;
  }

  public Info getLogout() {
    return logout;
  }

  public void setLogout(Info logout) {
    this.logout = logout;
  }

  private Info login;
  private Info logout;
}


class Info{
  public Info() {
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getLink() {
    return link;
  }

  public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  private String name;
  private String link;
  private String title;
}
```

Then use the following code to bing the json to the class

```
View v = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_STRING, View.class);
```

This would bind the json to an object of the class View.

Comment: Although that is likely functional, it is much too verbose, and too inflexible (would require a new private member for every map entry in the JSON file.  @BijuKunjummen answer (TypeReference) was what was needed/missing.